# Open native video player (full screen) when video is pressed in a WebView

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-video-player

My app uses a WebView. I need to open a native video player any time a user clicks on a video. I see that sometimes in sites, if you click on a video thumb, it opens a dialog asking you how you want to open it (via web or a video player).

What can I do on the server side or my app so an intent like this will be sent after a click on a video?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question got a little sideways at the end, but I'll respond to the base question.

1.) "I need to open a native video player any time a user clicks on a video"

Verify the link is a video, and fire an intent for ACTION_VIEW, Here's an example:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".mp4")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } 
        else
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
```

Comment: I am trying the same but shouldOverrideUrlLoading never get called. I think it is because I am using loadDataWithBaseUrl method.